# save user's extra details on signup firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I want to save the user's extra details i.e number, age only when the user signup(one time). But there is no callback for to check if the signup was successful or not.

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) {
  // Handle Errors here.
  var errorCode = error.code;
  var errorMessage = error.message;
  // ...
});
```

so what to do when you want to store the data only one time when the user signup rather using

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
  } else {
    // No user is signed in.
  }
});
```

which will be fired every time user login/logout but I dont want to save the extra signup details every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` return a promise, which has both a `catch()` and `then()` method you can respond to.

The Firebase documentation intentionally doesn't use then `then()` clause, since it's in general better to respond to the `onAuthStateChanged()` event (which also fires when the user reloads the app and is still signed in. Even in your case that might be the better place to put the code to store the user profile, as some of the data might change when the app reloads.

But if you want to explicitly respond to "the user was created successfully", you can do so with:

```
firebase.auth()
    .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then(function(user) {
        console.log("Create user and sign in Success", user);
    });
```

Comment: If I use `onAuthStateChanged()` how I can make sure that data is only written when the user is created i.e I do not want to save the same birthday again and again.

Comment: That would require reading the data (which defeats the purpose of not writing it) or keeping a local snapshot of what you wrote (which has a risk of getting out of sync when the same user signs in on multiple devices). I'm pretty sure the gains are not worth the effort in this case.

Answer (score 7):

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword($scope.email, $scope.password)
        .then(function(user) {
            var ref = firebase.database().ref().child("user");
            var data = {
                email: $scope.email,
                password: $scope.password,
                firstName: $scope.firstName,
                lastName: $scope.lastName,
                id:user.uid
            }
            ref.child(user.uid).set(data).then(function(ref) {//use 'child' and 'set' combination to save data in your own generated key
                console.log("Saved");
                $location.path('/profile');
            }, function(error) {
                console.log(error); 
            });
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            var errorCode = error.code;
            var errorMessage = error.message;
            if (errorCode == 'auth/weak-password') {
                alert('The password is too weak.');
            } else if (errorCode == 'auth/email-already-in-use') {
                alert('The email is already taken.');
            } else if (errorCode == 'auth/weak-password') {
                alert('Password is weak');
            } else {
                alert(errorMessage);
            }
            console.log(error);
        });
```

[image: Here's the result]
Here I have saved data in 'user.uid' key which is returned by firebase upon successful registration of user.